# Pass a variable into .setAttribute method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have following code:

```
for (var k = 0; k < id_arr.length; k++) {
    if (k === 0) {
        sets[k].setAttribute("style", "grid-column: col 1  / span 1; grid-row: row; margin-top: 40px");
    }
    if (k === 1) {
        sets[k].setAttribute("style", "grid-column: col 18  / span 1; margin-top: 40px");
    }
}
```

What I wanna do is to make an expression like this one:

```
if (k <= 10) {
   for (var j = 5; j < 15 ; j++){
        sets[k].setAttribute("style", "grid-column: col {{j}}  / span 1;");
    }
}
```

How can I pass this j inside .setAttribute method?

Comment: Do you want to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: `"some text"+j+"more text"` ?

Comment: Side note: Setting the `style` attribute is almost never best practice. Instead, either use classes, or set properties of the `style` **object**: `sets[k].style.gridColumn = "...";`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`template litteral`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

your line will become

```
sets[k].setAttribute("style", `grid-column: col ${j}  / span 1;`);
```

notice the use of `` ` `` instead of quotes

everything inside of a `${...}` block is evaluated as javacript meaning you can do

```
a = `${1 + 2}` // a = "3"
b = `${a} + 2 = ${a + 2}` // b = "3 + 2 = 5"
```

or even function call

```
function to(a, b) {
    let res = ""
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i++) {res += ` ${i}`}
    return res
}
b = `1 to 5 :${to(1, 5)}` // b = "1 to 5 : 1 2 3 4 5"
```